# ABP Framework: Background Job Disable Retry

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am using background job for some definition operations. Some of the definitions can completed in 2 minutes, some in 10 minutes.

I don't want  it to retry on fail. The job shouldn't retry  when it success or failed.Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the same [question](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=8701) asked in the https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com.

> - Write your code in try-catch and hide exceptions. Background job manager only retries on exceptions.

https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=8839&sid=4a5bed7481fd06bb89d8e98eb3c5cb12#p8839

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Jobs#configuration

You can change the `DefaultTimeout` value to 0

**References:**

1. https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/8158